# Process Builder - order processes run

Tags: process-builder, order-of-execution

We have multiple processes in Process Builder.  When these are listed, they are listed in alphabetical order.  Is there any way to control the order in which they are run?  For example, I want a process to set a record type, and then another process which will depend on the record type being set.  In this case, I need the first process to run before the second one.  Is there any way of actually doing this?

Comment: There is no logic to what order they are executed, however if you can take some of the logic outside of the process itself and move them into Flows, you can daisy chain your flows in whatever order you wish from a single process. Really depends on your situation what what you're actually doing within your processes.

Comment: @cricketlang You probably should have added this as an answer-- I would have.

Answer (score 2):

There is no logic to what order they are executed, however if you can take some of the logic outside of the process itself and move them into Flows, you can daisy chain your flows in whatever order you wish from a single process. Really depends on your situation what what you're actually doing within your processes. You can reference [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) article for the order of execution provided by Salesforce just in case you didn't know already.